# pass a model from partial view to controller by ajax in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

My controller is

```
public ActionResult AddCustomer(Customer SM)
{
    DataAccessLayer.ConClass obj = new DataAccessLayer.ConClass();
    obj.SaveCustumerDetails(SM);
    ModelState.Clear(); 
    return PartialView();
}
```

my model is

```
public class Customer
{
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Customer_id { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Customer_Contact_Person { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Customer_Contact_Person_Designation { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
      public string Customer_name { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Customer_Address1 { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Customer_Address2 { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Customer_City { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Customer_State { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Customer_Country { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Customer_PIN { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Customer_Phone1 { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Customer_Phone2 { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Customer_Email1 { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string Customer_Email2 { get; set; }
}
```

Savecutomer is the name of the button .My partaial view code is

```
<script>
  $('#SaveCustomer').click(
    function () {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("AddCustomer", "Customer")',
        data: ' $("myform").serialize() ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function (data) {
      },
    });
  });
</script>
```

My need is to save customer details when i click on `savecustomer` button I don't want to see the details on url. In this way url holds data. I need to avoid it.

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem and what's the question here, could you be more specific?

Comment: Your method needs to be marked with `[HttpPost]`. If what you have shown is your GET method, then remove the `Customer SM` parameter (never pass a model to a GET method) and remove the `obj.SaveCustumerDetails(SM);` and `ModelState.Clear();` (you should not be saving data in a GET method) and add a POST method.

Comment: Also you should not have `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` and you specify `dataType: 'json',` yet the controller method you have shown returns html which would throw an error also. And then you dont do anything with the data you return anyway. Its very unclear what your really trying to do.

Comment: @MaxBrodin How can I pass entire model to my controller by ajax

Comment: @StephenMuecke Can You suggest some edits on the   ` data: '$("myform").serialize() ,`

Comment: I have noted some of your current errors, but its still not clear what the method you have shown is. Is it marked with `[HttpPost]` and if so, then you need to show your GET method as well

Comment: @sarath Try `$("#myform").serialize()`

Comment: Note also scripts should never be in partial view - move it to the main view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke  This  fine when i individually pass items   data: { name :' +$('#cusname') +'}'

Comment: Whats fine? Nothing in your current code will work. You need to answer my queries if you want to solve this.

Comment: Try to serialize your form to JSON, see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mbrodin/6jm34h2n/2/)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please go through the answer , but actually i need to pass the entire data as a model.. so i need corection in  the data: onlly i think....because i made change in data: and controller part i given there only not added anything

Comment: I fairly clear that your refusal to answer my queries means you don't want to solve this so good luck.

Comment: not refusal @StephenMuecke i need solution from you..when i included [HttpPost] it does not work fine

Comment: My question was _Is the method you showed a GET or a POST?_ - Its now clear that it was a GET so I can give you an answer :)  (will add shortly, but perhaps next time you should consider responding to the query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you have shown is a GET but its parameter is `Customer SM` which means that the `DefaultModelBinder` will generate a query string for each property in your model. I'm guessing that (because this method returns a partial view) your calling it in the main view using `@Html.Action()` or `ajax` to load a form into the view.

Firstly you need to methods, one GET and one POST

```
public ActionResult AddCustomer()
{
  // Initialize a new instance of your model and pass it to the view
  Customer model = new Customer(); 
  return PartialView(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddCustomer(Customer SM)
{
  DataAccessLayer.ConClass obj = new DataAccessLayer.ConClass();
  obj.SaveCustumerDetails(SM);
  return Json(true); // see notes below
}
```

Note if you have included `@Html.AntiForgeryToken` in the partial, then your will also need to add `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`

Next, delete the script from your partial view and add it to the main view (scripts should never be in partials). Then change the script to

```
$('#SaveCustomer').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("AddCustomer", "Customer")',
    data: $('#myform').serialize(), // change this to include the #
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      // do something?
    },
  });
});
```

Note this assumes your form has `id="myform"`. Note also `contentType` has been removed (its not required unless you stringify the data). It can also be simplified to

```
$.post('@Url.Action("AddCustomer", "Customer")', $('#myform').serialize(), function(data) {
  // do something
});
```

Side notes: Its not clear what you want to do in the success callback. I would suggest that in the POST method you use `return Json(true);` if the save was successful, otherwise return a HTTP error code. Then in the success call back you might do something like

```
if (data) {
  // the save was successful so reset existing form controls
  $('#myform').get(0).reset();
  // maybe display a message indicating success
}
```

and similarly you could handle an error by displaying a message indicating the the customer could not be saved.

Answer (score -2):

When i changed to

```
$('#SaveCustomer').click(

   function () {
   $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '@Url.Action("AddCustomer", "Customer")',
           data: "{'Customer_Name' :        '" + $('#Customer_Name').val() + "' ," +
                  " 'Customer_Adress1' :      '" + $('#Customer_Address1').val() + "'}" ,


           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           dataType: 'json'

       });
   })
```

and change controller to

```
       public ActionResult AddCustomer(string Customer_Name, string Customer_Address1)
    {

        DataAccessLayer.ConClass obj = new DataAccessLayer.ConClass();
        obj.SaveCustomerDetails( Customer_Name,  Customer_Address1);
        ModelState.Clear();
        return PartialView();
    }
```

it worksss